# Underlines of MaskedTextBox disappear

Tags: vb.net, winforms, maskedtextbox

i have a problem in Windows Forms. I've created a form where I can enter the first and last name and click on the Search-Button to show another form with the following code:

```
Private Sub btnSearchUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchUser.Click

    If Me._clsfrmChild Is Nothing Then
        Me._clsfrmChild = New clsFrmChild
    End If

    If Me._clsfrmChild.ShowDialog = False Then
        Me._clsfrmChild.ShowDialog(Me)
    End If
```

In the second form I have a MaskedTextbox:

[Empty MaskedTextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0agg.png)

Whatever I do, If I close the second form with Visible = False and reopen it again, the MaskedTextBox looks like this:
[MaskedTextBox without underlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KgaA.png)

I close the second form that way:

```
Private Sub btnAbort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAbort.Click
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Does someone of you know why this problem is caused?

Comment: This is interesting to say the least `If Me._clsfrmChild.ShowDialog = False Then`

Comment: @T.S. What do you mean?

Comment: My answer is the answer for that

Comment: @T.S. Thank you. I will try this out!

Answer (score 0):

This is really not the way you supposed to work with dialogs. The proper way is this

```vb
dim result as DialogResult
using f as Form = New MyForm()

    result = f.ShowDialog()
    ' here you can work with form's public properties etc
end using

' optionally here you can continue massaging the result
if result = DialogResult.Ok then
   ' do for ok result
else
   ' do for other result. You can have severul results - add elseif
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make a dialog with results in general. This will be similar to how `MessageBox.Show()` works.

```
Public Class clsFrmChild

    Private Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Shadows Function Show() As DialogResult
        Dim result As DialogResult
        Using f As New clsFrmChild()
            result = f.ShowDialog()
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub OkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OkButton.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CancelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelButton.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note the constructor is privatized so there is no more `Me._clsfrmChild = New clsFrmChild`. You will see the displaying of the modal dialog is much simpler when called like `MessageBox`

```
Private Sub btnSearchUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchUser.Click
    Dim result = clsFrmChild.Show() ' static method call instead of instance method
    Select Case result
        Case DialogResult.OK
            MessageBox.Show("Ok")
        Case DialogResult.Cancel
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel")
    End Select
End Sub
```

If you are not interested in returning a standard `DialogResult`, you could change the return type to whatever you like such as a custom class, with more information (such as you want to return a string in addition to DialogResult) i.e.

```
Public Class clsFrmChildResult
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property DialogResult As DialogResult
End Class

...

Public Shared Shadows Function Show() As clsFrmChildResult
    Dim result As clsFrmChildResult
    Using f As New clsFrmChild()
        Dim dr = f.ShowDialog()
        result = New clsFrmChildResult With {.Text = TextBox1.Text, .DialogResult = dr}
    End Using
    Return result
End Function

...

Private Sub btnSearchUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchUser.Click
    Dim result = clsFrmChild.Show()
    Select Case result.DialogResult
        Case DialogResult.OK
            MessageBox.Show("Ok")
            Dim myString = result.Text
        Case DialogResult.Cancel
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel")
    End Select
End Sub
```